# problems when data transfer between different computer architectures

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing, data-transfer, cpu-architecture

I have a question about data transferring between different computer architectures. 
What kind of problems can occur while conversioning of ***integer, float and char*** type data specifically in this procedure? Could you please give brief info with these specific types?

I searched for it but couldn't find any necessary info. 
Any info will be apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a specific procedure. It's quite general. Would you please specify that what the source arch and the target arch look like?

Comment: Yes actually quite general but my teacher asked this question and I think she just wants me to talk about the possible general problems while transferring, what can happen to integer data, float data and char data respectively? How can they be effected from transferring? For example data can be padded with zeros, etc...

Comment: Read about _big endian_ and _little endian_ architectures and think about the size in bytes of each of those integer types.

Comment: @user1349536 This is not a right place to ask general questions if you don't expect us to write a book for you.

Comment: Look at things like numeric rounding and character truncation. Also how null values are handled differently etc.

Answer (score 2):

The big differences when porting code between architectures on modern machines are:

1. The size of a pointer: 32-bits vs 64-bits for example.
2. The size of a long: usually the same as the size of a pointer.
3. The byte order: big endian or little endian (or some ancient machines were middle endian).
4. Binary floating point vs decimal floating point: decimal floating point is a recent standard having been added in 2008. This isn't a common issue, but many machines do not have hardware support (are IBM Power machines the only ones?) for decimal floating point and have emulation libraries.

There are a few more things when talking about really old machines:

1. The length of a machine word: related to pointer size
2. The number of bits in a byte: this is now standardized at 8, but 40+ years ago, this wasn't the case.
3. The representation for a floating point number.  Before IEEE-754, there was no standard and different machines had different representations.  VAX with its two floating point types is probably one of the most famous examples.
4. The representation of negative numbers.  Machines today use two's complement.  The Cray 1 famously used one's complement.